# For-loop breaking Python Splinter Browser instance

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, splinter

I'm trying to use Splinter and Python to cycle through text files and upload certain values to websites based on what is in the files. I can do this with one file when I hard code it, but for whatever reason whenever I try and use a for-loop or while-loop to cycle through all my text files, the browser instance I have just closes. No errors, it just stops.

```
def postads(browser):
    for i in range(1,adcount): #<----Code Breaks right here
        count = 0
        temp = open("ads/%s.txt" %i,"r")
        name = temp.readline()
        cat = temp.readline()
        price = temp.readline()
        temp.readline()
        temp.readline()
        desc = ""
        templ = temp.readline()
        while templ.strip()!="":
            print(templ)
            desc+=templ
            templ = temp.readline()
        pics = []
        templ = temp.readline()
        while templ!="":
            print(templ)
            pics.append(templ[:-1])
            templ = temp.readline()
        link = "Website"+str(cat)+"&amount"+str(price)+"&title="+str(name)+"&description="+desc+""
        print(name)
        print(cat)
        print(price)
        print(desc)
        print(pics)
        print(link)
        browser.visit(link)
        for i in pics:
            response = requests.get(i)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                f = open(filet, 'wb')
                f.write(response.content)
                f.close()
            browser.attach_file("files[]",filet)
        button = browser.find_by_id('pstad-frmsubmit')
        while(True==(browser.is_text_present('Please wait'))):
            break
        button.click()
        while(False==(browser.is_text_present('Verified'))):
            break


def browserSesh():
    browser = Browser()
    # Visit URL
    url = "url"
    browser.visit(url)
    browser.find_by_id('login-email').fill('username')
    browser.find_by_id('login-password').fill('password')
    button = browser.find_by_id('btn-submit-login')
    button.click()
    while(False==(browser.is_text_present('Valid text'))):
        break
    postads(browser)

browserSesh()
```

There isn't an explicit error message, but these are the final lines in the console:

```
2017-12-08 09:34:46 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:61908/session/50bcaca3-83dc-40c3-8acb-a73f4bd9378d/element {"using": "css selector", "value": "body", "sessionId": "50bcaca3-83dc-40c3-8acb-a73f4bd9378d"}
2017-12-08 09:34:46 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-08 09:34:46 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:61908/session/50bcaca3-83dc-40c3-8acb-a73f4bd9378d/element/eb1de3b0-b547-4637-8d1e-2e9d4c31e123/text {"id": "eb1de3b0-b547-4637-8d1e-2e9d4c31e123", "sessionId": "50bcaca3-83dc-40c3-8acb-a73f4bd9378d"}
2017-12-08 09:34:46 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
```

I've tried different iterations of this (opening the browser using the "with" method, for-loops, while-loops, in functions, out of functions) and I'm just really lost. I couldn't find any answers on stackoverflow, so I thought it would be worthwhile posting.

I suspect it has something to do with python interpreting that the beginning of the for-loop signifies that the browser is no longer needed.

Comment: can you paste the error you are getting?

Comment: @Satish Edited the original post